# A property about normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $L$ be a normal operator (i.e. $LL^*=L^*L$).
Prove that there exist a unitary operator $U$ such that $L^*=UL$.

My approach is to first define $U$ on the $\operatorname{range}(L)$ and try to extend it to the whole space. But it seems not easy to extend. To respond to the comments:

1. I do not know the spectral theorem for normal operators. I only know the spectral theorem for compact operators and bounded self-adjoint operators.
2. I have tried to use that $H=\overline{\operatorname{ran}}(L)\oplus\ker(L)$ and extended $U$ by the identity on $\ker(L)$, but failed.

Comment: My approach is to first define U on the range(L) and try to extend it to the whole space. But it seems not easy to extend.

Comment: Do you know the spectral theorem for normal operators?

Comment: @PhoemueX I do not. I only know the spectral theorem for compact operators and bounded self-adjoint operators.

Comment: Your idea is quite good. Use that $H=\overline{\mathrm{ran}}(L)\oplus \mathrm{ker}(L)$. On $\mathrm{ker}(L)$, you can extend $U$ by the identity.

Comment: @MaoWao Can you say something more concrete? I have tried that way, but failed.

Comment: @Akatsuki You should copy your comments into the question. This question is in the review queue and may be closed, and then deleted, I guess because people don't read the comments...

Comment: @user1729 Sorry I didn't see it before. Thank you very much for the revision :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment:

On $\mathrm{ran}(L)$ define $U$ by $ULx:=L^\ast x$. From $L^\ast L=LL^\ast$ it follows easily that $\|Lx\|=\|L^\ast x\|$ for all $x\in H$, in particular, $Lx=Ly$ implies $L^\ast x=L^\ast y$ for all $x,y\in H$.

Thus, $U$ is well-defined on $\mathrm{ran}(L)$, has image $\mathrm{ran}(L^\ast)$, and $\|ULx\|=\|L^\ast x\|=\|Lx\|$ for all $x\in H$. Hence it extends to a unitary operator $\overline{\mathrm{ran}}(L)\to\overline{\mathrm{ran}}(L^\ast)$.

Further notice that $\|Lx\|=\|L^\ast x\|$ for $x\in H$ implies $\ker L=\ker L^\ast$ and consequently $\overline{\mathrm{ran}}(L^\ast)=(\ker L)^\perp=(\ker L^\ast)^\perp=\overline{\mathrm{ran}}(L)$. Thus, $U$ is a unitary operator $\overline{\mathrm{ran}}(L)\to\overline{\mathrm{ran}}(L)$.

Now $H=\overline{\mathrm{ran}}(L)\oplus \ker L^\ast$. Define $U$ to be the identity on $\ker L^\ast$. Then $U$ is clearly surjective on $H$, and $\|Ux\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in H$ follows easily from the orthogonality of the decomposition of $H$. Hence $U$ is unitary (more generally, unitary operators $U_i\colon H_i\to H_i$ induce a unitary operator $U_1\oplus U_2\colon H_1\oplus H_2\to H_1\oplus H_2$).

The relation $L^\ast=UL$ was obviously built into the definition of $U$.